# Eth Blockchain API call - GET token price at a particular DateTime or block number

Tags: transactions, ether

I'm trying to build a simple web app for personal use to track my dex trades (UniSwap only atm). I've been looking at some ETH APIs that are available; Etherscan API, Ethplorer API and Blockfi API. I've managed to grab all transaction associated with token and a wallet (pretty much all of the above APIs offer this). I'm struggling to find a response that provides the price of the token at the purchased date. I can use the transaction hash, hit an API and it'll return the DateTime that the transaction was confirmed.

I was hoping that I could either hit a transaction endpoint on an ETH blockchain API and within the response it'll return the amount of token purchased/the price of the token at that point in the time (Couldn't find an endpoint that returns the price) OR another idea was to use the block number/DateTime and work out the price from that.

^^ I'm struggling with find an API that will help with the above idea, can anyone point me in the right direction please

Comment: this is done by processing swap events (using filtering feature in geth) , you get all `Swap` events and then based on in/out amount calculate the price for any date

Comment: there probably lots of APIs already made to get this, so you don't have reinvent the wheel, check out dune analytics website, it is all in SQL